# Can I maintain xml format except a changed target like below or maintain a original format?

Tags: java, xml

I want to maintain original xml format after changing some attribute values. How can I maintain format except changing attributes?

I`m on java8, apache9, eclipse oxygen.

For example, my example XML is

```
    <a>
     <b id="123"
        name="456"
        value="789">
     <c id="awe"
        name="try">
    </a>
```

and I use code like this.

```
    Document doc = getConfigDocument();
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("serverInfo");


                       Element oasisElement = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("b").item(0);
    oasisElement.setAttribute("id", "1231");

    Transformer tr;
    try
               {
                   tr = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
                   tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
                   tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                   tr.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(new File(getConfigRoot())));
                   resultMsg = "success";
               }
```

after this code, XMl will be rewritten, and change format like this.

```
<a>
 <b id="1231" name="456" value="789">
 <c id="awe" name="try">
</a>
```

Can I maintain xml format except a changed target like below or maintain a original format?

```
<a>
 <b id="123" name="456" value="789">
 <c id="awe"
    name="try">
</a>
```

Comment: Although I don't see a point in why you want to maintain certain formatting if everything else is working for you but still I'll risk asking :p
Why do you need to maintain the formatting?

Comment: Because we use many xml attributes to define our server status. So we see this xml in many times to confirm, thus we need easy to read.....:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the XML parser doesn't report the detailed layout to the application, so the application (in this case, the XSLT processor) is not able to retain the original layout.

If the input format follows systematic rules, however, then you may be able to get the serializer (which processes the result of the XSLT transformation) to follow the same rules. If you used the Saxon serializer rather than the built-in JDK (Xalan) serializer, then you could get something very close to your input format by specifying serialization properties:

```
indent=yes
saxon:indent-spaces=1
saxon:line-length=10
saxon:attribute-order="id name value"
```

For this you would need Saxon-PE or higher.